# max in multi-dimensional list python from a file

Tags: python, file

hey please I need to know soon as possible how to get the max from a file .csv in the whole file and I'm just beginner at python I learned yesterday I search a lot ten I find this code but it's not useful for me:

```
import csv #librairies
import math
with open('Classeur8.csv') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=";")
    linecount=0
    id_max=0
    temp_max= -math.inf
    for row in reader:
        if linecount==0:
            print(f'column names are {",".join(row)}')
            linecount +=1
        else:
            print(f'our id is {row[0]} and temperature is {row[1]} ')
            linecount +=1
            if float(row[1]) > temp_max:
                id_max,temp_max=row[0],float(row[1])
    print(f'processed lines:{linecount}')
    print(f'max_id:{id_max} and max_temperature:{temp_max}')
```

***Classeur8.csv***

```
id;temperature
2;23
3;33
4;43
5;53
6;63
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is not clear from your post what is not working for you. Since you say you are new to Python, we'd rather make sure you know how to run a python script and format python code. Please correct the code formatting  in your post.

Comment: sorry can you clarify more??

Comment: @DmitriChubarov the Classeur8.csv it's my file.csv i wrote it by using excel the code here just what i found during my research but what i want really is the maximum value in whole file did you get what i mean or not??

Comment: @DmitriChubarov yes sir i use pycharm 2022 like an ide to run my code

Comment: @DmitriChubarov absolutely sir for example if i change the values and let my file.csv contain                                                                                                                        id;temperature
2;23
3;33
4;123
5;53
6;63                                                                                                                                will be 4 as an id and 123 as a temperature is it correct just because there's a relation between this two values ?? what i want really as an output just 123

Comment: @DmitriChubarov what should i do??

Comment: @DmitriChubarov get it but it's working with me i think i could not post a picture in comments

Comment: Now this looks like a working code. It correctly outputs `max_id:4 and max_temperature:123.0` when you change `4;43` to `4;123` now what is your desired output?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov i would the maximum value in whole file only 123

Comment: Did you try to replace the last two lines with `print(temp_max)` to print just the number?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov if i did that i'll know where's the maximum value located if we have another columns contain the max number then what you write it's not what i would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pandas: This has inbuilt functions such as `Sum`, `Max`, `Min`, `AVG`, etc.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('Classeur8.csv', sep=';')   

#FINDING MAX
p=df['temperature'].max()    

print(p)
```

Comment: hello i get this message {ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'}

Comment: @Davy Bellens i learned before sql and i find that function sum max min avg in it is it the same in python??

Comment: You were right @DmitriChubarov it needed quotes indeed.
Your computer doesn't have the module pandas yet so in command prompt you must type "pip install pandas" and then you will be able to execute the code.

Comment: I install the interpreter pandas but even though it's not working there 's an error in temperature

Comment: @中国在年之前我们也 what is the exact name of the column with the temperatures?

Comment: I believe in pandas you need to specify the column separator explicitly if it is not a comma. In the OP example I would suggest `df=pd.read_csv('Classeur8.csv', sep='[;\s]+', engine='python')`

Comment: i have two columns id and temperature

Comment: @DmitriChubarov separator is semicolon

Comment: @DmitriChubarov could you please explain to me why do you wrote engine='python'???

Comment: @中国在年之前我们也 You might need `engine='python'` to specify a regular expression for separator.

Comment: yeap it's working perfectly and also I tried to wrote the code without engine and also sep=';'    it's working too @DavyBellens

Comment: @中国在年之前我们也 can you mark my answer with the green checkmark? then I get points :)

Comment: @DavyBellens hey i'm new in this plateform how i can do it

Comment: but you should correct it like @DmitriChubarov said